# Exporting builtin variables in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, built-in

That might be a trivial question, but what is the right way to use builtin variables in a shell script? For example, if I want to write a script that opens default text editor, which is specified in $EDITOR. Just using

```
export EDITOR
```

won't help. I found out that defining EDITOR variable helps to solve that problem:

```
#!/bin/bash    
export EDITOR=vim
$EDITOR
```

The above will work, but is there a way to export the variable without defining it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would that accomplish? No, you cannot export something which does not exist.  Why would you want to export something from a script which only runs the thing you just defined? You seem to be confused about what `export` does.  Perhaps you should update your question to explain why you are asking this.

Comment: Maybe this can help?  A common scenario is that you want to run `EDITOR` if it defined, and otherwise fall back to, say, `nano`.  A compact and idiomatic way to do that is `${EDITOR-nano}`

Comment: Ask it on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

`EDITOR` is not a "builtin" variable, and you can export it (i.e. make it an environment variable) whenever you like. Nothing magical here. While it is true that bash interprets this variable in certain situations, it is quite common that applications access this variable, when they want to launch an editor, so in practice, `EDITOR` **is** usually exported. For example, I have in my .zshrc and .bashrc the line

```
export EDITOR=nano
```

To your question: You can export a varible with an *empty* falue, like this

```
export EDITOR=
```

but I don't see what you will gain from it.

If you just want to ensure, that your shell script and all descendent processes have EDITOR set, a common idiom is

```
: ${EDITOR:=vim}
export EDITOR
```

If the user of your script doesn't define this variable, it is set here - you just need two lines, because bash syntax does not permit to combine this into a single one.

Comment: You can collapse it to one line with `export EDITOR=${EDITOR:-vim}`, but that's arguably no better than simply using two lines.

Comment: I like your suggestion. From the viewpoint of maintenance, it is IMO slightly better.